# How to pull out a dta when it shows <-!--Content End--> after the JavaScript?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've just started to learn python. I want to extract glass temperature data every three hours for academic purpose. The website is below:

https://www.weather.gov.hk/wxinfo/ts/display_graph_grass_e.htm?kp&

[image]

I try to use BeautifulSoup to pull out the data using the below script. Here is the result:

[image]

Before I find the wanted data, there is a < !--Content End-- > after the JavaScript and I can't scrape the script behind it. Why would that happen and if there is any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored as Javascript `Array` in the HTML page. We can use `re` and `ast.literal_eval` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) to retrieve it:

```
import re
import requests
from ast import literal_eval

url = 'https://www.weather.gov.hk/wxinfo/ts/display_graph_grass_e.htm?kp&'

html_text = requests.get(url).text

station_code = literal_eval(re.findall(r'StationCode\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])
station_name = literal_eval(re.findall(r'stnname\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])
station_height = literal_eval(re.findall(r'stn_height\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])
grass_temp = literal_eval(re.findall(r'grasstemp\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])
min_since_17 = literal_eval(re.findall(r'minSince17\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])
min_hour = literal_eval(re.findall(r'minHour\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])
min_minute = literal_eval(re.findall(r'minMinute\s*=.*?(\(.*?\))', html_text)[0])

rows = [*zip(station_code, station_name, station_height, grass_temp, min_since_17, min_hour, min_minute)]

headers = ['Station Code', 'Station Name', 'Station Height', 'Grass Temp', 'Min_since_17', 'Min Hour', 'Min Minute']
print(''.join('{: <20}'.format(d) for d in headers))
for row in rows:
    print(''.join('{: <20}'.format(d) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
Station Code        Station Name        Station Height      Grass Temp          Min_since_17        Min Hour            Min Minute          
kp                  King's Park         65                  25.4                25.3                23                  35                  
tkl                 Ta Kwu Ling         15                  25.4                24.8                17                  00                  
tms                 Tai Mo Shan         955                 21.3                21.3                07                  19
```